# JavaScript: how to change CSS style of created span?

Tags: javascript, colors, html

```
  newNode = document.createElement("span");
  newNode.innerHTML = "text";
  range.insertNode(newNode);
```

Is it possible to make the text in innerHTML with red background color?  I want to add style="background-color:red" to just created span. Is it possible? Or it must have some id, and then I can change this span with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

Answer (score 8):

Simple enough:-

```
newNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 5):

Better to give a classname for the span

```
<style>
    .spanClass { background-color: red; }
</style>

newNode.className = "spanClass";
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
var spanTag1 = document.createElement('span');
spanTag1.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">text</span>';
```

OR

add `class` using `js` and set `css` to that `class`

```
var spanTag1 = document.createElement('span');
spanTag1.className = "mystyle";
```

Now set `style` to that `class`

```
<style> 
    .mystyle {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes directly to the DOM object. The style attribute can be assigned by this way too. Example:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.setAttribute("style","color:white;background-color:red;");

var text = document.createTextNode("My text");
span.appendChild(text);
```

Of course you have to add this element created to their parent object in your page:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parentObject");
parent.appendChild(span);
```

This method "setAttribute()" lets you to add other non-standard attributes used by animations and custom jquery options to your HTML standard tags.